# Why wont curve modifier work across whole mesh? i have added loop cuts as well

Tags: modifiers

[image: Image of curve modifier not working]

Curve Modifier not working on whole mesh
I am making a tire for a car as you can see in the image below, but the curve modifier is only affecting one half of the mesh, please advise why this is happening.
I have tried extruding and nothing happened, scaling does not show any affect either.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your curve has been looped (cyclic).

Enter edit mode, select any point on the curve and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> (Toggle cyclic). If curve become cyclic, the curve modifier will deform
the object using curve at any possible position.

Comment: Thanks! ill try this

Comment: @Amogh don't forget to mark the answer as correct then